# Extracting username alone from an email address list

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I need to extract only the username from a column holding list of email addresses separated by `;`

[Column Name]
Email Addresses

```
user1@gmail.com;user2@gmail.com;user3@gmail.com
```

I want the output as `user1;user2;user3`

How do I get it in sql query?

Comment: which type of sql Database ?

Comment: SQL server 2012

Comment: Is the mail domain the same always? I mean is it always @gmail.com or it can vary?

Comment: no its not @gmail.com always,it can vary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really **never ever store more than one value in one cell!!!**
This is breaking `1.NF` already...
What you should do: Introduce a `1:n`-related table to store each eMail-address with a a foreign key to its owner separately.

With SQL Server 2016 you could use `STRING_SPLIT()`, but with your version you must use one of the many workarounds. In the following code I use the *XML trick* first to splitt your string at each semicolon. The final `SELECT` combines `LEFT()` AND `CHARINDEX` to cut away the rest:

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(YourEMail VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
    ('us&er1@gmail.com;user2@gmail.com;user3@gmail.com');

SELECT LEFT(eMailAddress.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),CHARINDEX('@',eMailAddress.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'))-1)
FROM @mockup AS m
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(m.YourEMail,';','$$SplitThisHere$$') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'$$SplitThisHere$$','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS A(xmlSplit)
CROSS APPLY A.xmlSplit.nodes(N'/x[text()]') AS B(eMailAddress)
```

If you need the usernames re-concatenated again (think about this!), you can change the final query to this:

```
SELECT STUFF(
(
SELECT ';' + LEFT(eMailAddress.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),CHARINDEX('@',eMailAddress.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'))-1)
FROM @mockup AS m
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(m.YourEMail,';','$$SplitThisHere$$') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'$$SplitThisHere$$','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS A(xmlSplit)
CROSS APPLY A.xmlSplit.nodes(N'/x[text()]') AS B(eMailAddress)
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @TempData TABLE(YourEMail VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @TempData VALUES
    ('user1@gmail.com;user2@gmail.com;user3@gmail.com');

;WITH Expected
AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(YourEMail, 1, CHARINDEX('@', YourEMail) - 1) AS YourEMail
    FROM (
        SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS YourEMail
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(YourEMail, ';', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS YourEMail
            FROM @TempData
            ) AS A
        CROSS APPLY YourEMail.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
        ) dt
    )
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((
            SELECT '; ' + YourEMail
            FROM Expected
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS EmailDesiredOutPut
```

OutPut

```
  EmailDesiredOutPut
  --------------
  user1;  user2;  user3
```

Reurning Email_String AS Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_ExtractName] (
@YourEMailIn nvarchar(MAX)
)
Returns varchar(max)
AS
Begin
DECLARE @YourEMailOut varchar(MAX)

DECLARE @TempData TABLE(YourEMail VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @TempData(YourEMail) 

SELECT @YourEMailIn

;WITH Expected
AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(YourEMail, 1, CHARINDEX('@', YourEMail) - 1) AS YourEMail
    FROM (
        SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS YourEMail
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                CAST('<S>' + REPLACE(YourEMail, ';', '</S><S>') + '</S>' AS XML) AS YourEMail
            FROM @TempData
            ) AS A
        CROSS APPLY YourEMail.nodes('/S') AS Split(a)
        ) dt
    )
    , FinalResult
    AS (
SELECT  DISTINCT STUFF((
            SELECT '; ' + YourEMail
            FROM Expected
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS EmailDesiredOutPut
       )
       SELECT @YourEMailOut=EmailDesiredOutPut From FinalResult

       RETURN @YourEMailOut

END
GO
```

--Call Function like below

```
 SELECT [dbo].[udf_ExtractName] ( 'user1@gmail.com;user2@gmail.com;user3@gmail.com') AS EmailDesiredOutPut
```

OutPut

```
EmailDesiredOutPut
-------------------
user1; user2; user3
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine but I'm trying to put this in a function and when i set output variable it's throwing error--->Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'.

Comment: Kindly check the question posted,i have edited by adding the function

Comment: Ok i will do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144572/discussion-between-srini131-and-jennifer-jes).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this code..Just replace variable name with your column name..

```
Declare @email nvarchar(50)='user1@gmail.com'
Select Substring(@email,0,CharIndex('@',@email))
```

Comment: OP has mentioned that a single column is holding list of email addresses. 'user1@gmail.com;user2@gmail.com;user3@gmail.com'

Comment: Your code will not work if the column holdind data like this 'user1@gmail.com;user2@gmail.com;user3@gmail.com;user4@gmail.com;user5@gmail.com'